# How to create new content in jekyll homepage

Tags: jekyll

I really wish I could generate a new page like "publications" in the navigation to show my work in progress. I  am using jekyll. And you can find my repository here: https://github.com/dangraeber/dangraeber.github.io .

In folder data and _workinprgress, I tried to configurate everything according to my understanding of how things work there. I am sorry for the uninformed question, but I am really new to this.

Best

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using [academicpages/academicpages.github.io](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io).

You need to add your new collection in your `_config.yml` for pages to appear.

```yaml
collections:
  workinprogress:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/
```

Also, you need an "index page" so `/workinprogress/` is reachable. There's an example in `_pages/portfolio.html` that looks like this:

```
---
layout: archive
title: "Portfolio"
permalink: /portfolio/
author_profile: true
---

{% include base_path %}

{% for post in site.portfolio %}
  {% include archive-single.html %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can take that file and replace some keywords, it'll (probably) work.

See [Jekyll documentation on collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/):

> If you’d like Jekyll to create a rendered page for each document in your collection, you can set the `output` key to `true` in your collection metadata in `_config.yml`.

Comment: Thanky you very much. As you might see, I implemented the change. But if I navigate to the section or collection, I get an error message telling me there is no content. The error reads "Page Not Found

Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist — perhaps you can try searching for it below."